# How to call function of module instances made from generate block?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have module instances made in a `generate` block and would like to call a function defined in the module similar to the code below:

```
module parent (...);
    ...
    genvar i;
    generate
      for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) begin : module_inst
          MyModule my_module(...);
      end
    endgenerate
    
    always@(...) begin
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            module_inst[i].function();
        ...
    end

endmodule
```

However, I get this error:

> function not declared under prefix module_inst/my_module

Is my syntax incorrect, or is this not possible to do?

I am able to call the function if I only create one instance:

```
module parent (...);
    ...
    MyModule my_module(...);
    
    always@(...) begin
        my_module.function();
        ...
    end
endmodule
```

The problem can be solved by manually creating each module instance and manually calling their respective functions, instead of using the `generate` and `for` loop statements. However, this would scale poorly and be hard to maintain. How can I go about doing this? I have found similar problems using tasks instead of functions where the suggested solution used classes; however, I'm unsure of its applicability to my problem as I need synthesizable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the module instance name (`my_module`) as well.  This code compiles without errors with multiple simulators:

```
module MyModule;
    function func1;
    endfunction
endmodule

module parent;
    parameter N=3;
    genvar i;
    generate
      for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) begin : module_inst
          MyModule my_module ();
      end
    endgenerate
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) begin
        always @* begin
            module_inst[i].my_module.func1();
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Note that the 2nd `for` loop is also a `generate` block.  The `generate/endgenerate` keywords are optional.

---

As a helpful debugging tip for `generate` constructs, I like to add this line inside the generated module (`MyModule`) to show the full hierarchical path:

```
initial $display("%m");
```